# How to aggregate subcategories in pandas.dataframe.pivot_table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I created a pivot table that is meant to count the total number of rejections for Types A-K and their subtypes (A1-A12)

```
piv_table2 = df.loc[(Filter1) & (Filter2)].pivot_table(
    values=["Level3"], 
    index=["Level1", "Level2"], 
    columns=None,
    aggfunc="count",
    margins=True,
    margins_name="Total"
)
```

This is what a sample of my input df looks like:

```
WeekNumber, Level1, Level2, Level3
22, H, H1, Obs
22, H, H2, Exc
23, B, B10, Obs
23, A, A6, Obs
```

The week number columns are the week number, Level1 is the high level category, with Level2 being subcategories, & Level3 being "Obs" or "Exc"

piv_table2 looks like this:

```
# piv_table2 Output
                Level3
Level1  Level2  
A   
        A1-     175
        A10-    2
        A11-    10
        A12-    30
...

K   
        K1 -    12
        K11 -   12
        K11 -   13
Total           5170
```

Essentially, I'd like to count the sub categories (A - K) along with the complete total of everything from A-K. Ideally, the output for piv_table2 would give me the total for all As, all Bs, all Cs, etc. AND then the sum of all those counts. The desired output would look something like this:

```
# Desired Output with Level1 Totals & Complete Totals
                Level3
Level1  Level2  
A -             617 
        A1-     175
        A10-    2
        A11-    10
        A12-    30
...

K -             12  
        K1 -    10
        K11 -   1
        K11 -   1
Total           5170
```

The totals for A & K, along with the totals for EVERYTHING from A-K are shown in the desired output.

I tried using pivot_table2.merge(pivot_table) & vice versa with no success.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. Please provide a [mre], meaning some example input data and the exact code you tried that didn't work, as well as desired output just to be clear. For specifics, see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341). BTW, if you want more tips, check out [ask].

Comment: can you run df.to_dict() and post the results into your question! Thanks! :-)

Comment: @Mark Based on the "Total", OP's df has 5170 rows -- too many to post. That's why I'm asking for an MRE myself.

Comment: @wjandrea true! i guess maybe the head of the df

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to add `Total` to `Level2` index and then final "grand-total":

```py
x = df.pivot_table(index=['Level1', 'Level2'], values='Level3', aggfunc='count')

# add "Total" to level2
total = x.groupby(level=0)['Level3'].sum().to_frame()
total.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([total.index, ['Total']])

x = pd.concat([x, total]).sort_index()

# add all Total
all_total = pd.DataFrame({'Level3': x.xs('Total', level=1).sum().squeeze()}, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('Total', '')]))

x = pd.concat([x, all_total]).sort_index()

print(x)
```

Prints:

```
               Level3
Level1 Level2        
A      A6           4
       A7           1
       A8           1
       Total        6
B      B10          2
       B11          1
       Total        3
H      H1           1
       H2           1
       H3           3
       Total        5
Total              14
```

---

Initial `df`:

```
    WeekNumber Level1 Level2 Level3
0           22      H     H1    Obs
1           22      H     H2    Exc
2           22      H     H3    Exc
3           22      H     H3    Exc
4           22      H     H3    Exc
5           23      B    B10    Obs
6           23      B    B10    Obs
7           23      B    B11    Obs
8           23      A     A6    Obs
9           23      A     A6    Obs
10          23      A     A6    Obs
11          23      A     A6    Obs
12          23      A     A7    Obs
13          23      A     A8    Obs
```